# How do I exclude SQL data that is in current Week of Year

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have some SQL which works well, except that I am continuously having to remove the first line of the results, as it only contains (at this point, being Monday 17th) data for part of the week, and being grouped by this field it is showing 'fake data'

Here is the current code:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(submitted)  YEAR,
    COUNT(request)   Total_Requests,
    DATEPART( wk, submitted) WEEK
FROM
    wv_external_statistics
WHERE
    userid <> 'anonymous'
GROUP BY
    YEAR(submitted),
    DATEPART( wk, submitted)
```

Here is some sample data:

```
YEAR | Total_Requests | WEEK
2017 |      361       | 28
2017 |     2486       | 27
2017 |     2860       | 26
2017 |     4521       | 25
2016 |     2600       | 52
2016 |     3028       | 51
....
```

As you can see the top row is the current week, and as we are only at the first day of the week the data is not complete, so I want to exclude this row from my results... I just tried the below, and immediately zero rows were found, so I am clearly doing something silly, which I am hoping someone can point out?

```
DATEPART( wk, submitted) <= DATEPART( wk, submitted)-1
```

NOTE: I need to keep all the data from the year 2016, even though it's week number will be greater than this week, the year will be from previous years. 
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the current week. Why not just throw this in the where clause...

Where
Datepart( wk, submitted) != datepart(wk,getdate())

Comment: that is great. How do i modify that to only exclude the row that is from the current year? As I will end up having data from Previous years, that are from the current week number, that I need to include in my results?

Comment: Add an  `or Datepart( year, submitted) != datepart(year,getdate())` and it works.

Comment: this will exclude rows from the current year, and row for the current week number from previous years

Comment: `(DATEPART( wk, submitted) != DATEPART(wk,GETDATE())
OR  DATEPART( YEAR, submitted) != DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()))` This works perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT YEAR(SubmittedDate) As [YEAR]
    ,COUNT(Request) As Total_Requests
    ,DATEPART(WEEK, SubmittedDate) As [WEEK]
FROM wv_external_statistics
WHERE UserID <> 'Anonymous' Or ((DATEPART(WEEK, SubmittedDate) - 
DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE()) = 0) And (YEAR(SubmittedDate) - YEAR(GETDATE()) = 0))
GROUP BY YEAR(SubmittedDate),DATEPART(WEEK, SubmittedDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify having condition (well, should admit its long, fuzzy and maybe not optimal)

```
SELECT
    YEAR(submitted)  YEAR,
    COUNT(request)   Total_Requests,
   DATEPART( wk, submitted) WEEK
FROM
    wv_external_statistics
WHERE
    userid <> 'anonymous'
GROUP BY
    YEAR(submitted),
    DATEPART( wk, submitted)
    having year(submitted) * 100 + datepart(wk, submitted) < (select max(year(submitted) * 100 + datepart(wk, submitted)) from wv_external_statistics)
```

because your condition (`DATEPART( wk, submitted) <= DATEPART( wk, submitted)-1`) is always false for each row in the query

Comment: I just threw that line in my SQL, and looked at the results, it is still showing this week and its low number in the Total_Requests Field... I will have to update my original question as I just realised it will start removing data from last year.